# How to make filters case insensitive in Vuejs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

I'm trying to build an application in `Vuejs 2` where I'm having a filter to find out the specific data from an array of elements. This filter is `case sensitive` but I want to have `case insensitive`, following is my code:

```
tableFilter: function () {
    if( this.model ) {
        return this.model.filter( 
            item =>
                item.clients_association.includes( this.search_by_name ) && 
                item.event_type.includes( this.search_by_event_type )
            )
            .map(
                d => (
                    {
                        id: d.id,
                        client_names: d.clients_association,
                        stellar_participants: d.stellar_participants,
                        contact_participants: d.contacts_association,
                    }
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Please guide me how can I achieve it.

Comment: I guess you can use the native string method `.toLowerCase()` in the conditional check of your strings. This will make both strings in the same case format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Array#includes` is [case sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Case-sensitivity) you can convert everything to lower case:

```
const searchTerm = this.search_by_name.toLowerCase();
const searchEvent = this.search_by_event_type.toLowerCase();

this.model.filter((item) =>
  item.clients_association.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) &&
  item.event_type.toLowerCase().includes(searchEvent)
);
```

You can also use [`String#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), which accepts a regex with the insensitive (i) flag, and returns `true` if the string matches the expression, or `false` if not:

```
const searchTerm = new RegExp(this.search_by_name, 'i');
const searchEvent = new RegExp(this.search_by_event_type, 'i');

this.model.filter((item) =>
  searchTerm.test(item.clients_association) &&
  searchEvent.test(item.event_type)
);
```